# R: Fill all NAs in a set of columns with the values above

Tags: r, tidyr, fill

I have a data frame and vectors of names of "a" columns and "b" columns:

```
x <- data.frame(a1 = c(1, NA, rep(1, 3), NA),
                a2 = c(2, NA, rep(2, 3), NA),
                a3 = c(3, NA, rep(3, 3), NA),
                b1 = c(10, 10, NA, rep(10, 2), NA),
                b2 = c(20, 20, NA, rep(20, 2), NA),
                b3 = c(30, 30, NA, rep(30, 2), NA),
                c = c(2, 3, 5, NA, 9, 8))
avars <- names(x)[1:3]
bvars <- names(x)[4:6]
```

Is there an elegant way - using dynamic variable name vectors 'avars' and 'bvars' - to fill out all the NAs in avars and bvars with the values above them.

I understand, I could use a loop like this:

```
library(tidyr)
for(i in c(avars, bvars)) x <- x %>% fill(!!i)
x
```

But maybe there is a more elegant solution?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::fill()` along with `grep` to make sure we only fill down `avars` and `bvars`:

```
library(tidyverse)

x %>% fill(grep("^[ab]", names(.)))

  a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3  c
1  1  2  3 10 20 30  2
2  1  2  3 10 20 30  3
3  1  2  3 10 20 30  5
4  1  2  3 10 20 30 NA
5  1  2  3 10 20 30  9
6  1  2  3 10 20 30  8
```

The RegEx expression `^[ab]` asserts that the column name has to start with either `a` or `b`

Or per your comment, using `avars` and `bvars`:

```
x %>% fill(grep(paste0(c(avars,bvars), collapse = "|"), names(x)))
```

Which is still better than the `for` loop solution, because it is vectorized.

Comment: This is nice, however, I'd like it done using avars and bvars.

Comment: @user3245256 This will work: `x %>% fill(grep(paste0(c(avars,bvars), collapse = "|"), names(x)))`

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept your answer. But it's interesting - how much longer the code it vs. the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Use `na.locf` from zoo package

```
> library(zoo)
> na.locf(x)
  a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3
1  1  2  3 10 20 30
2  1  2  3 10 20 30
3  1  2  3 10 20 30
4  1  2  3 10 20 30
5  1  2  3 10 20 30
6  1  2  3 10 20 30
```

Comment: This is nice, thank you! But how can I make sure that it's done ONLY for avars and for bvars? Assume I have a few more columns for which I don't want the fill to happen. I added column c in my data frame x for that purpose. I don't want to touch c.

Comment: `x[, c(avars, bvars)] <- na.locf(x[, c(avars, bvars)])` or using `data.table`, `library(data.table); setDT(x)[, c(avars, bvars) := na.locf(.SD), .SDcols=c(avars,bvars)]`